# Why is generate-id() function returning the same id twice?

Tags: xslt, xalan

I have some XSLT that I didn't write but I have to maintain it. At some points it is using generate-id() to create an empty div which is then manipulated by a script further on. Problem is that the div is inside another div (i had thought this was a bit pointless, but acceptable anyway) and both are being given the same id! I tried this with Xalan and then again with the JRE transformer with the same result. I then tried to use the Eclipse/Xalan XSLT debugger and when i am stepping over the thing, it all works correctly...

The XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="listed">
    <xsl:variable name="showwhat">
        <xsl:call-template name="IdentifyAudience"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($showwhat) &gt; 0">
        <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>   
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="Blah"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And the XML fragment is like this:

```
<listed id='ID39AF705AE17A000F337B000A' mode='html'>
    <ul>
        <li>Blah blah</li>
    </ul>
</listed>
<listed id='ID39AF715892AE000F337B002B' mode='html'>
    <ul>
         <li>Blech blech.</li>
    </ul>
</listed>
```

I appreciate this is a bit complicated - any clues? Please?

Comment: Your statement that you get incorrect results cannot be reproed unless you provide a complete XML document (as minimal as possible) and a complete XSLT transformation (as minimal as possible). Please, provide these, or your question isn't really a question that can be answered.

Comment: What is the XML fragment you posted? If it is the result, it hasn't been generated with that XSLT code, since that one generates `div`s with `id` but there is not `div` in the result.

Comment: @Dimitre - ok I thought someone might have have run into something similar to do with generate-id in similar circumstances. Both the XML and XSLT run over 10k lines but I will produce a minimal example.

Comment: Yes, I am eager to have a look. Could you, please, notify me via a comment about the update?

Comment: @khachik - Sorry I should have clarified. The XML i posted is the input and the XSLT transforms it into HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is in the code you haven't show to us.**

`generate-id()` function return an unique identifier string **for argument node or the context node otherwise**.

So, it's unique for unique node... You are probably calling the p/0 function in two content template with the same context node. How is this posible? Well...

```
<xsl:call-template name="Blah"/>
```

`call-template` instruction **does not change the context node**

Comment: Yes, that was it exactly! All I had to do was add the node name to call like: generate-id(listed) - simplez. What threw me was how Xalan in debug mode didn't exhibit the same behaviour! I guess there is some problem with context in it somewhere...

Comment: @jambox: I'm glad it was helpful, ask any time.